# how to select the images differently from array using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have store 10 images in NSArray.
In UIViewController i placed 6 UIImageView,and given the outlet in .h file.

I need to select any  6 images from the array how to do?
And need to display the images in UIImageView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
         images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"], nil];

            NSString *dd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", images];
            NSLog(@"%@",dd);
  }          
    - (void)setImagesForImageViews:(NSArray<UIImageView*>*)viewsArray fromArray:(NSArray<UIImage*>*)imageArray {
        if(images == nil || viewsArray == nil || viewsArray.count > images.count) {
            return; // early return
        }

        NSMutableArray* randomImageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:viewsArray.count];
        while (randomImageArray.count < viewsArray.count) {
            UIImage* image;
            do {
                NSUInteger random = (NSUInteger)arc4random_uniform(images.count);
                image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:random];
            } while ([randomImageArray containsObject:image]);
            [randomImageArray addObject:image];
        }
        [viewsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImageView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            obj.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:idx];
        }];
    }
```

in .h file

#import

```
@interface memory_test : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *images;
}
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b1;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b3;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b4;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b5;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b6;
```

Comment: set random any three image?

Comment: question is not clear. Do you want to show 3 random images ?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking for. please mention what have you done and what issue you're facing. SO is not for asking questions about howtos

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose(as the question is not clear), you want to set random images to imageviews from an array of images. The challenge here is to find the random image, non-repeating, ofcourse from an array.

I haven't tested the code, but something like this should work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray* images = [self imagesArray];
    NSArray* views = [self imageViewsArray];
    [self setRandomImagesForImageViews:views fromArray:images];
}

- (NSArray<UIImage*>*)imagesArray {
    return @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"]];
}

- (NSArray<UIImageView*>*)imageViewsArray {
    return @[_b1, _b2, _b3, _b4, _b5, _b6];
}

- (void)setRandomImagesForImageViews:(NSArray<UIImageView*>*)viewsArray fromArray:(NSArray<UIImage*>*)imageArray {
    if(imageArray == nil || viewsArray == nil || viewsArray.count > imageArray.count) {
        return; // early return
    }

    NSMutableArray* randomImageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:viewsArray.count];
    while (randomImageArray.count < viewsArray.count) {
        UIImage* image;
        do {
            NSUInteger random = (NSUInteger)arc4random_uniform(imageArray.count);
            image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:random];
        } while ([randomImageArray containsObject:image]);
        [randomImageArray addObject:image];
    }
    [viewsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImageView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        obj.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:idx];
    }];
}
```

You can remove your images array declaration from your header file if you are not using it again in the class.

Comment: i have 6 UIImageview then how to set

Comment: You can make it more generic by saving imageview oulets inside an array.

Comment: @teena: Changed the code, you jus t need to pass the images array and imageview array to this function.

Comment: how to call this function in view did load

Comment: @teena: I guess you already have an image view array. You need to create an array of your imageviews and then call this function with both imageview array and image array.

Comment: i have edited the code now.please check.In this what should i need to add

Comment: @teena: How are your imageviews set? In nib? Please include that as well.

Comment: i have set in the uiviewcontroller

Comment: @teena: Yes I got that but you just need to create an array of there references and pass it to the function. You are almost there.

Comment: i have 10 images in the array .and have 6 UIImageView in UIViewcontroller  then i need to select 6 images from the array.please check above ,i have edited the question

Comment: @teena: Paste the code for imageview IBOutlets as well.

Comment: how to call in view did load

Comment: there is showing an error as implicit conversion loses integer precision NSUInteger to unint32.And the image is not displaying in the screen

Comment: @teena: That is not an error, but a warning and if the image is not displaying you would need to debug. I cant say why it is not getting displayed.

Comment: @teena: Were you able to debug the issue?

Comment: value is entering but not displaying the image.

Comment: : 6 images are not displaying

Comment: @teena: It difficult to say why this is happening. How to debug the code is essential for any software developer. My advise for you is to learn debugging. SO community can help you to an extent, and its very important to know what to ask on SO to get maximum help. Simply asking the same question won't help you much. In my view you should try to understand why and how things are happening rather than achieving the end result/output.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR SWIFT**

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //array with ImageView
    @IBOutlet var imageViews: [UIImageView]!
    //array with Image
    lazy var imagesArray = [UIImage]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //initiate image
        let imageOne :UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "exchange")
        let imageTwo :UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "indexPhone")
        let imageThree :UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "indexCheer")
        let imageFour :UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "indexTrade")
        let imageFive :UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "indexWashMachine")

        //add image to array
        imagesArray = [imageOne,imageTwo,imageThree,imageFour,imageFive]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    //Action for Button
    @IBAction func randomSelect(_ sender: Any) {
        //temporary array for images
        var tempImageArray = imagesArray

        for imageView in imageViews{
        // get random index for array images
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tempImageArray.count)))
         // set random image for ImageView
         imageView.image = tempImageArray[index]
         // remove arleady added Image from temporary array
         tempImageArray.remove(at: index)



        }
    }

}
```

**FOR OBJECTIVE-C**

```
@interface ViewController ()
//array with ImageView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imageViews;
//array with Image
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* imagesArray;

- (IBAction)randomSelect:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     //initiate image
    UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"exchange"];
    UIImage *imageTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indexCheer"];
    UIImage *imageThree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indexPhone"];
    UIImage *imageFour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indexTrade"];
    UIImage *imageFive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indexWashMachine"];

    //Initiate array with image
    self.imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageOne,imageTwo,imageThree,imageFour,imageFive, nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)randomSelect:(id)sender {
    //temporary array for images
    NSMutableArray* tempImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.imagesArray];

    for (UIImageView* imageView in self.imageViews){
        // get random index for array images
        int index = arc4random()%(tempImageArray.count-1);
        // set random image for ImageView
        imageView.image = [tempImageArray objectAtIndex:index];
        // remove arleady added Image from temporary array
        [tempImageArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}
```

Comment: i need in objective-c

Comment: 5 minutes , i'm remaking for obj-c

Comment: i have 6 UIImageview then how to set

Comment: Your count of Image more large than count of ImageView?

Comment: If you count if imageView more than Image ,  comment this row "[tempImageArray removeObjectAtIndex:index]"