# how to select random images from array using UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

i stored 10 images in array as below.

```
 images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"], nil];
```

in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *images;
```

as i stored 10 images in array .from this i need to select random 6 images and need to display in the UIImageView .

In UIViewController i have placed 6 UIImageView and the connection as below.

```
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b1;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b3;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b4;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b5;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b6;
```

Then how to do?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [how to select the images differently from array using objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559004/how-to-select-the-images-differently-from-array-using-objective-c)

Comment: A note that you shouldnt store `UIImage` in array, it might crash your app due to lack of memory, you should store only the name string and use it later in your b1-b6

Comment: @Tj3n how to store the name string

Comment: The name string is something like `tree.jpg`, `Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg`,.... then only add it to `UIImageView`'s image  when needed

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution, Try this

```
NSUInteger randomIndexValue = arc4random() % [images count];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to firstly find the random index of array. then you can access the index data. here i sample code of swift.

```
let randomIndex = arc4random() % 10
let image = imageArray[randomIndex]
```

now you can use the image for imageview. hopefully you can convert it to objective c.

Comment: i need in objective-c

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getRandomValueFromArray:(NSMutableArray*)arrAllData randomDataCount:(NSInteger)count {  
 NSMutableArray *arrFilterData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0; i<count; i++){

 NSInteger index = arc4random() % (NSUInteger)(yourArray.count);
[arrFilterData addObject:[arrAllData objectAtIndex:index]];
[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
return arrFilterData;
}
```

give your own count.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually 5 images two times, so you'll get minimum one double on your imageViews.

```
static NSArray *imagenames = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    imagenames = @[
        @"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg",
        @"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg",
        @"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg",
        @"tree.jpg",
        @"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg",
        @"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg",
        @"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg",
        @"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg",
        @"tree.jpg",
        @"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"];
});

NSArray<UIImageView *> *imageViews = @[self.b1, self.b2, self.b3, self.b4, self.b5, self.b6];
NSMutableArray * tmpnames = imagenames.mutableCopy;
for (UIImageView *imageView in imageViews) {
    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)tmpnames.count);
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tmpnames[randomIndex]];
    [tmpnames removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
}
```